# Compilation error, undefined reference to Test(), multi file C program

Tags: c

Trying to compile a .c program to initiate a server gives me an error of an undefined function I have on another .c program (even though I have a .h linking them).

I'm doing a project of a C# client connected with a server with a C script. I'm using zinjai as my IDE and I'm trying to implement and split the project in 2 major files, one consists of the server script and the other consists of a database C script.
I've created a .h file in orther to link them but I don't manage to make it work.

This is only a part of the project just to test if it works, I return 0 because I want tom print it as a way to see if it works.
This is a part of the lets say a.c:

```c
//include base de datos y mysql
#include <mysql.h>
#include "basedatos.h"

int Test(){
    return 0;
}
```

This is the .h file:

```c
#ifndef BASEDATOS_H
#define BASEDATOS_H

int Test();

#endif
```

This is the main .c file, lets say b.c:

```c
#include <mysql.h>
#include "basedatos.h"
//obviously there's some code here:

    for( ; ; ){

        printf ("Escuchando\n");
        printf ("%d", Test());

        sock_conn = accept(sock_listen, NULL, NULL);
```

I'm expecting to see the program compile and print a '0' but when I try to compile it, this error shows up:

undefined reference to Test()

collect2: error: Id returned 1 exit status

I repeat, I'm using zinjai with this compile options: `-std=c99 mysql_config --cflags --libs -lm`

Comment: Is your .h file in the correct folder?

Comment: I think so, all of this files are made in a separate way from scratch, but in the same folder.

Comment: This is a linking error; make sure to link the object created by `a.c`, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Zinjai, but with most IDEs you need to create a project in order to compile and link multiple source files into your executable.